# Unexpected infinite expression occurring in PolyLog

Tags: bugs, special-functions

I'm getting an infinite expression error when numerically evaluating the standard Clausen function Cl6, defined in terms of `PolyLog` as:

```
Cl6[x_] := Im[PolyLog[6, Exp[I x]]]

Cl6[1/10^14] // N (* works fine *)

Cl6[1/10^15] // N (* yields Inifinite expression *)
```

The last statement yields:

```
                                      -72        -71
                                  0. 10    - 0. 10    I
Divide::infy: Infinite expression --------------------- encountered.
                                             -142
                                        0. 10
```

I would expect a number close to zero. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I'm using Wolfram Language 13.0.0 Engine for Linux x86 (64-bit).

Note: Exactly the same happens when using `ResourceFunction["ClausenCl"][6, x]`. It also happens (but with some smaller input) for `ResourceFunction["ClausenCl"][5, x]`.

Comment: The bugs tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions.

Comment: Apparently you can get a numerical approximation by using either machine-precision arguments (`Cl6[1.*^~15]`) or arbitrary-precision arguments (``Cl6[1.`20*^-15]``), but not with the symbolic argument you proposed. That is odd behavior indeed.

Comment: Many thanks for the hint! Although, as far as I can tell, this issue is also present with limited-precision numeric (i.e. non-symbolic) input: `Cl6[N[#,40]& @ (2Pi + 10*^-39)] // N[#,40]&`

Comment: Alexander, as I'm sure you've realized as well, the problem resides within `PolyLog`. I am not convinced that this should be happening; in fact, the documentation for `PolyLog` mentions that it "can be evaluated to arbitrary numerical precision", and yet that doesn't seem to work here. The workaround presented below notwithstanding, I recommend that you simplify the issue to concentrate on PolyLog and report it to Wolfram Support.

Comment: You are right, of course. I'll send a bug report to Wolfram.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Cl6[x_] := Im[PolyLog[6, Exp[I x]]]

Cl6[1/10^14] // N

(* 1.03693*10^-14 *)
```

As you indicated the limit is zero

```
Limit[Cl6[x], x -> 0]

(* 0 *)
```

For very small real arguments, use [`Asymptotic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Asymptotic.html)

```
Cl6A[x_] = Asymptotic[Cl6[x], {x, 0, 3}] // Simplify[#, Element[x, Reals]] &

(* -(1/6) x^3 Zeta[3] + x Zeta[5] *)

Cl6A[1/10^#] & /@ Range[15, 50, 5] // N

(* {1.03693*10^-15, 1.03693*10^-20, 1.03693*10^-25, 1.03693*10^-30, 
 1.03693*10^-35, 1.03693*10^-40, 1.03693*10^-45, 1.03693*10^-50} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is of course a nice workaround! For me `Series[Cl6[x], {x, 0, 3}]` worked as well.